# Insert value if not exists in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
create table #tableA(id int, val varchar(50))
create table #tableB(id int, val varchar(50))
create table #tableC(id int, val varchar(50))
create table #tableD(id int, val varchar(50))

insert into #tableB values (1, '11');
insert into #tableB values (2, '22');
```

I want insert value for #tableD and my condition is

1. if `#tableA` has a value then

   ```
   insert into #tableD  
       select * 
       from #tableA;
   ```
2. if `#tableA` is empty then

   ```
   insert into #tableD  
       select * 
       from #tableB;
   ```
3. if `#tableA` and `#tableB` are empty then

   ```
   insert into #tableD  
       select * 
       from #tableC;
   ```

How can I do this the simplest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Transact-SQL statement [IF..THEN..ELSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql)

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TableA) 
BEGIN 
   insert into #tableD  select * from #tableA;       
END
ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #TableB) 
BEGIN
  insert into #tableD  select * from #tableB;
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
  insert into #tableD  select * from #tableC;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

two basic ways but not good if the number of temp tables is dynamic. Note I use * in the queries, but best practice to specify columns

The first works fine but may be slow on huge data, and does extra work than needed, but if a small data set it should be ok

```
insert into #tabled
select * from #tablea union all
select * from #tableb where 0 = (select count(*) from #tableA) union all
select * from #tablec where 0 = (select count(*) 
                                 from (select top 1 id from #tablea 
                                       union all 
                                       select top 1 id from #tableb 
                                       ) x
                                 )
```

or the second way works ok, and only does the work neccessary.

```
insert into #tableD select * from #tableA
if @@rowcount = 0
begin
   insert into #tableD select * from #tableB
   if @@rowcount = 0
   begin
     insert into #tableD select * from #tableC
     if @@rowcount = 0
     begin
       print('no rows inserted')
     end
     else
     begin
        print('rows inserted from C')
     end     
   end
   else
   begin
     print('inserted from B')
   end
end
else
begin
   print('insert from A')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
if exists (select 1 from #tableA)
    begin
       insert into #tableD
          select * from #tableA
    end
else
    begin
       insert into #tableD
          select * from #tableB
    end

if not exists
    (select 1 from #tableA union select 1 from #tableB)
    begin
       insert into #tableD
          select * from #tableC
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use (Transact-SQL) `EXISTS` to insert the value based on conditions

```
if exists (select * from #tableA)
begin
    insert into #tableD  select * from #tableA;
end
else
begin
    insert into #tableD  select * from #tableB;
end
if not exists (select * from #tableA)  
begin
       if not exists (select * from #tableB)
       begin
       insert into #tableD  select * from #tableC;
       end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
INSERT INTO #tabled 
    SELECT * FROM #tableA
UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM #tableB
UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM #tableC
```